# Script works on every post but not the last post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, http

My script removes the http:// and www from urls displayed in a post's content but for some reason it either affects all the posts but the last one or just the first post of the page depending on where I place the script.

For instance if it's in the loop it will affect all the posts but the last but if it's outside the loop it only affects the first post.

I'm looking for a solution so that it takes affect on all urls being displayed on a page. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php 

        if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>



            <Script>

            $(document).ready(function removeFunction() {
            let post_id = '<?php global $post; echo $post->ID; ?>';
              var str = document.getElementById("link" + post_id).innerHTML; 
              var res = str.replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?/i, "").split('/')[0];
              document.getElementById("link" + post_id).innerHTML = res;

            });

           </Script>



<p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
<!-- This is where the URL's are EX: <a id="link[return_post_id]" href="http://example.com/">http://example.com/</a> -->



<?php endwhile;

    else :
    echo '<p>No content found</p>';

    endif;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You tagged jQuery there so put jQuery code outside of loop.

2.It has to iterate over all `<p>` and do what you are doing.

3.Change `<p><?php the_content(); ?></p>` to `<p data-id="<?php global $post; echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php the_content(); ?></p>` (inside `while` loop)

4.After above steps followed, change jQuery code like below:

```
<Script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('p').each(function(){

            let post_id = $(this).data('id');
            var str = $(this).html(); 
            var res = str.replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?/i, "").split('/')[0];
            $(this).html(res);
        });

    });

</Script>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem and this is on mixture of php and javascript.
Your php code Generate JS Within a Loop, in each loop it will create a function named **removeFunction()** and your browser interpreter mixed up things. it will replace the last one.

There Are 2 Solution for Your problem:
First is to make These Functions Distinct like This:

```
$(document).ready(function removeFunction<?php echo $post->ID; ?>() {
```

this will make function names as removeFunction1() removeFunction2() ...

The Second Sulotion is  to Define The function outside The loop and in the php loop just call the function like this:

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<script>
removeFunction(<?php global $post; echo $post->ID; ?>);
```

and your function definition would be like this:

```
removeFunction(post_id){
```